# Как убрать обновление страницы при отправке формы

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, html, javascript

При отправке формы при помощь этого кода страница обновляется.

Что сделать, чтобы она не обновлялась? Просто срочнейшим образом нужно.
JS и PHP вообще не знаю, код писал друг))

Если никто не хочет браться безвозмездно - заплачу немного))

Просто завтра нужно уже сдать сайт, а у меня еще ничего не работает нормально :(

```
<?php

class Mail {

private $_plain = "text/plain";

public function isTypeHtml($is_html = true) {
    if ($is_html == true) {
        $this->_plain = "text/html";
    } else {
        $this->_plain = "text/plain";
    }
}

public function send($to, $to_name, $from, $from_name, $subject, $message) {
    $headers = "From: =?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($from_name) . "?= <$from>\r\n";
    $headers .= "To: =?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($to_name) . "?= <$to>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Subject: =?utf-8?b?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: $this->_plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: Mansi studio.\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
}

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->isTypeHtml(false);
$message = "Полное имя заказчика: " . $_POST["fio"] . "\n\r";
$message .= "Его почта или телефон: " . $_POST["email"] . "\n\r";
$message .= "Сообщение: " . $_POST["message"] . "\n\r";

if ($mail->send("director@escolaboratory.com", "Имя получателя", "director@escolaboratory.com", "Новое сообщение!", "Новое сообщение!", $message)) {
    echo ""; //Если сообщение отправлено
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Как вариант, можно добавить в скрипт обратный редирект (на страницу, с которой производится запрос. Или использовать JS.

Comment: На клиенте надо повесить preventDeafault на событие submit формы и отправлять данные ajax-ом. Таким образом, при включенном javascript, страница обновляться не будет. Server-side тут даже не затрагивается.
Если точнее
    $('myform').submit = function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax(........);
    }